# How to hide the soft navigation bar(virtual buttons) of android device for whole application?

Tags: android

I want to hide the soft navigational bar i.e. virtual buttons of android device for whole app. I have used below code snippet

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

to hide it but when i slide gridview it will become visible .

Comment: Isn't it like you are blocking your user to do anything. Which might be against O.S. guidelines

Comment: No, It is possible i have seen it in many apps .

Comment: for that you need to use fullscreen activity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Immersive flag for setSystemUiVisibility() lets your app go truly "full screen." [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Try below code, for immersive mode.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if (hasFocus) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my life :) This works amazingly

Comment: This is works effectively for all devices version & manufacturer kind! Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
```

// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.

```
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```